# JS Amcharts map breaks on chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

AmCharts map doesn't show correctly on chrome and firefox. Microft Edge, Safari are just fine.

But when I zoom out to 90%, it looks okay. On 100%, it's broke.

What is the problem? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to report their bug tracker.

Comment: Could you provide more details? We're not aware of any issues with Chrome and Firefox. Post a fiddle with your code that reproduces this so we can help troubleshoot.